# two versions of xcode (the latest version is always selected)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Currently I have xcode 4.2 installed in /Developer but I wanted to install a lower version of xcode for some reasons. So, I downloaded xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg from Apple Developer website and installed it in /Developer2. Whenever I run Xcode.app in /Developer2/Applications, I always get xcode 4.2 running. Even if I "open with" my .xcodeproj and navigate to my /Developer2/Applications/Xcode.app, xcode4.2 is always selected as the default program. So how  can I choose xcode 4.1 to run instead of xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running "xcode-select" from the command line? Usually the command goes like:

```
xcode-select -switch /Path/To/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xcode-select` to choose the Xcode you like.

`xcode-select -print-path` will print all the Xcode available in your system.

`xcode-select -switch /Path/To/Developer` will switch to the special Xcode.

Comment: I did this earlier:
sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer2/Applications/Xcode.app/

then this: xcode-select -print-path
the result: /Developer2/Applications/Xcode.app

so it should be running my xcode4.1 but its still running the 4.2

Comment: xcode-select -print-path the result: /Developer2/Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: /Developer is the xcode4.2 I want to select xcode4.1. I already did the switch. See my first comment on your answer. The switch works but still 4.2 is called when xcode runs.

Comment: @Diffy I made a mistake, try `sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer2` only.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click any XCodeProj, it will give you an option to open it with Xcode 4.1 or 4.2. Opt for Xcode 4.1. If still it opens Xcode 4.2. Then you might want to uninstall, and make a fresh install of Xcode. ideally, both should run. Check this out::

http://www.ioslearner.com/how-to-run-multiple-xcodes-in-your-mac/